# Semantic UI cs and js files for dropdown menus

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'm creating Semantic UI 2.1.7 dropdown menus but it is not showing.  I have the code below and it seems I included the necessary css and js files.  Am I missing other files? Do I need to include css and js files per component instead of just one?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Semantic UI Sign In/Sign Up Form</title>

  <link href="semantic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <style type="text/css">

  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="ui inverted menu">
  <div class="header item">Brand</div>
  <div class="active item">Link</div>
  <a class="item">Link</a>
  <div class="ui dropdown item">
    Dropdown
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item">Action</div>
      <div class="item">Another Action</div>
      <div class="item">Something else here</div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <div class="item">Separated Link</div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <div class="item">One more separated link</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right menu">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="ui transparent inverted icon input">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="item">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>


  <!-- content will go here -->


  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="semantic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  </script>      
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make dropdowns work make sure to install node 4.x and build from gulp.